# listingsutf8's option inputencoding=utf8/latin1 leads to latin1.def to be read each time a listing is used

Tags: listings, input-encodings, listingsutf8

**Edit:** `inputencoding=latin1` option initially written should have been `inputencoding=utf8/latin1`

If the `listingsutf8`'s option `inputencoding=utf8/latin1` leads to `latin1.def` file to be read each time a listing is used, as pointed out by the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.code}
Foo
\end{filecontents}

% \lstset{inputencoding=utf8/latin1}

\begin{document}
\multido{}{1000}{%
  \lstinputlisting{\jobname.code}
}
\end{document}
```

It could lead to significant waste of time: the compilation `time pdflatex test` of this MWE gives, with the line `\lstset{inputencoding=utf8/latin1}`:

- commented:

  > pdflatex test  1,68s user 1,49s system 99% cpu 3,189 total
- *not* commented:

  > pdflatex test  2,66s user 2,26s system 99% cpu 4,956 total

Do you see a way to make the `latin1.def` file to be read just once?

Comment: It is **only** 178 lines long, and **only** 114 lines are actual contents.

Comment: @Symbol1 Nevertheless, in a document e.g. using `beamer` class, with numerous listings (some of them repeated multiple times because of overlays), it could make a difference.

Comment: The option `inputencoding` is, obviously, for the included contents. Hence it is 100% safe to include the definition file once you enter the environment and forget the definitions once you leave. One might try to use a "universal" encoding (UTF-8 for instance) so they need not to "change" the encoding entering and leaving the environment.

Comment: Internally listings uses the `\inputencoding{latin1}` from inputenc which simply reads the def to setup the definitions. You could store the definitions in some command (with one argument) e.g. \latinonedef and then do `\usepackage{etoolbox}\preto\lsthk@Init{\let\inputencoding\latinonedef}{}{}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Okay but shouldn't such an improvement be implemented in the package code?

Comment: Whose package code? listings is simply using the latex/inputenc interface to switch the inputencoding. So imho one would need a extended version of inputencoding which stores the definitions and allows to switch without reloading the file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer But why the `inputencoding=utf8/latin1` option of  `listingsutf8` doesn't silently do what you suggest?

Comment: This, including UlrikeFischer's suggestion, does not make much sense (to me). Storing something in a file versus in a macro do make difference, of course. One is in hard disk and one is in memory. But a "good" operator system can simply cache the file, so now there is no difference. Please someone do the test and tell me I mislooked something.

Comment: @Symbol1 Running `time pdflatex video` (`video.tex` being a rather big `beamer` document) on my Linux box gives (1) without Ulrike suggestion `pdflatex video  43,95s user 1,49s system 99% cpu 45,629 total` (2) with Ulrike suggestion `pdflatex video  31,24s user 1,32s system 75% cpu 42,993 total`. So the difference is significant, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I have to say yes. I guess you can answer your own question now.

Comment: @Symbol1 Well, I would prefer Ulrike to answer it: that's her suggestion :)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer What you suggested has a funny drawback with `\lstinline` that you can see by compiling a document whose body is `The macro \lstinline|\foo| is a so nice!`.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé: Well you see it is not so easy. You could try `\preto\lsthk@Init{\def\inputencoding#1{\latinonedef}}{}{}` instead. And pay attention to spurious spaces ...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sigh... spurious spaces... Seems to work nicely now :) If you give these hints as an answer, I could accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package `listingsutf8` re-encodes the listing file from UTF-8 to the specified 8-bit encoding before passing it to `listings`. Since the encoding actually changes, package `\inputencoding` loads the new definitions for the active characters of the encoding from the `.def` file (`latin1.def`). These re-definitions has to be repeated each time the encoding is changed.

The following code hacks into macro `\inputencoding`, catches the call of `\input` and redefines it temporarily. The new definition loads the file into a macro via package `catchfile`. Then the next time, this global macro is used instead of loading the file. Since the `.def` files for `inputenc` should not contain weird stuff like category code changes, a simple macro can be used here. Otherwise the contents would have to be passed through the slower `\scantokens`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.code}
Foo
\end{filecontents}

\lstset{inputencoding=utf8/latin1}

%%% Begin hack
\usepackage{catchfile}
\let\SavedInputEncoding\inputencoding
\renewcommand*{\inputencoding}{%
  \let\TempSavedInput\input
  \let\input\CachedInput
  \SavedInputEncoding
}
\newcommand*{\CachedInput}[1]{%
  \let\input\TempSavedInput
  \ifcsname CachedInput@#1\endcsname
  \else
    \CatchFileDef\TempCachedInput{#1}{}%
    \global\expandafter\let\csname CachedInput@#1\endcsname\TempCachedInput
  \fi
  \let\TempSavedEndinput\endinput
  \let\endinput\relax
  \csname CachedInput@#1\endcsname
  \let\endinput\TempSavedEndinput
}
%%% End hack %%%

\begin{document}
\multido{}{1000}{%
  \lstinputlisting{\jobname.code}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Listings(utf8) uses the standard interface `\inputencoding{XXX}` from the `inputenc` package to change the various encoding related definitions. `\inputencoding` loads the definitions from the XXX.def-file. While it is certainly possible to store the definitions in a macro instead of reloading them from the `.def` I don't think that `inputenc` should do it by default. The case that a document switches often the input encoding is rather rare. It is also rather rare that listings contains non-ascii-characters.

In your case you can do something like this:

```
\newcommand\latinonedef[1]{%
 % definitions from latin1.def
 % with/without the \providecommands as needed
 % carefully remove all spurious spaces!
 }

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\preto\lsthk@Init{\let\inputencoding\latinonedef}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: As you said, it is not so easy: it leads to the error `! Illegal parameter number in definition of \lsthk@Init.` as soon as `\lstset{language=bash}` (`bash` is just an example) is used after the line `\preto\lsthk@Init{\def\inputencoding#1{\latinonedef}}{}{}`.

Comment: I knew I had a reason why I used \let. But you naturally must define \latinonedef as a command with an argument (like \inputencoding}. I have edited the answer.

Comment: I've complained about this before and I think it was Heiko that provided a solution that cached (?) the def file and disabled the multiloading. I can check my archives tomorrow.

Comment: You say "It is also rather rare that listings contains non-ascii-characters" . I agree except for listings with comments in other languages than English.